# Is there a way to have line breaks between keywords in JabRef?

Tags: bibtex, jabref

Recently shifted to JabRef v 3.2, and am loving it so far, but for one issue. The keywords are very hard to read if there are a lot of them, and especially if they have similar words. Is there a way to force linebreaks after the keyword separator.

What happens now is:

```
Keyword1, Keyword2a Keyword2b, Keyword3
```

What I would like to see is:

```
Keyword1,
Keyword2a Keyword2b, 
Keyword3
```

Comment: please add a feature request at https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that, after posting the issue, I received and answer. You can view the answer at (https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/1226#issuecomment-211415428)

If you don't feel like going over there yourself, here is the text of the way to fix this issue.

> This is indeed the default behavior. However, you can instruct JabRef not to remove the new lines in the keywords field as follow:
>
> - Options -> Preferences
> - Select "File" on left panel
> - In "Do not wrap the following fields when saving:", add "keywords"